# Can cats.effect.IO be sequenced, ie is it in the Traverse typeclass?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I like to sequence collections of effects eg  to turn a `List[IO[Int]]` into a `IO[List[Int]]` like so :-

```
scala> import cats._, cats.data._, cats.implicits._, cats.effect._

scala> val efs : List[IO[Int]] = List(IO(1),IO(2))
efs: List[cats.effect.IO[Int]] = List(IO$647684131, IO$2021068036)

scala> var efOfInts = efs.sequence
efOfInts: cats.effect.IO[List[Int]] = <function1>

scala> efOfInts.unsafeRunSync
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

But is it possible to go the other way? eg to turn a `IO[List[Int]]` into a `List[IO[Int]]` ?

I cant seem to find the implicits to add `sequence` onto IO so now I'm wondering if it is not possible to Traverse or Sequence IO?

Has anyone done this or know why it is not allowed?

Thanks.

Comment: `IO[List[Int]] -> List[IO[Int]]` doesn't make any sense. You have a IO that will produce `List[Int]` and you want to convert it to List of IO where each IO produce a single Int? Which sounds like breaking the a IO into multiple IO which is not possible. You can compose IOs to make bigger IO but you can't decompose IO to smaller IOs much like function where you can't decompose the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not allowed.

The whole idea of IO is that you cannot get values out of it without `unsafeRunSync`. There is no "peeking inside"

Since Traversable also means Foldable, let's look at why something like `foldLeft` on IO breaks the looking inside rule.

```
def foldLeft[A, B](fa: IO[A], b: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B
```

So for example if we had an `x: IO[Int]` (which produces `2`)

foldLeft(x, 0)(_ + _), that would have to return us a `2`. So we have peeked inside. `foldLeft` would have to `unsafeRunSync`, which breaks referential transparency.

So for this (and other similar) reasons, you cannot have `Traverse` on `IO`.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. :-)